# Domain of value in an inequality

Tags: inequality

I have such a problem:

$\forall x \in (1, +\infty)$, the inequality $2x + m + \frac{2}{x -1} > 0$ is always true. Then the domain of value of the real number $m$ is
\begin{equation}
A. m < -8  \hspace{1in} B. m > -8 \hspace{1in}C. m < -6  \hspace{1in}D. m > -6.
\end{equation}
This is what I have done:

Let $f(x) = 2x + m + \frac{2}{x-1}$. Then,
\begin{equation}
\frac{df(x)}{dx} = 2 - \frac{2}{(x-1)^2}.    \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Let $\frac{df}{dx} = 0$, we get $x=2$ or $x=0$. Take $x=2$ because $x \in (1, +\infty)$. Then $f(2)$ is an extremum. Further, for $1< x \leq 2$, $\frac{df}{dx} \leq 0$; and for $x \geq 2$, $\frac{df}{dx} \geq 0$. So $f(2)$ is a minimum. That is
\begin{equation}
f(2) = 6 + m > 0.  \tag{2}
\end{equation}
So,
\begin{equation}
m > -6.    \tag{3}
\end{equation}
I chose D. But the answer says D is wrong. I am puzzled. I have checked my calculation several times but didn't find anything wrong. Am I wrong or is the answer wrong?

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me as well. I am not sure either what is wrong. Here is my desmos plot (without the $m$ term): https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDfog.png

Comment: agreed; $$2x+\frac2{x-1}=2(x-1 + \frac1{x-1})+2 = 2((\sqrt{x-1}-\frac1{\sqrt{x-1}})^2+2)+2 =2(\sqrt{x-1}-\frac1{\sqrt{x-1}})^2+6\ge 6 $$

Answer (score 1):

**Proposer is right,another solution is:**

For $x>1$, we have $f(x)=2x^2+x(m-2)+(2-m)>.0$, this means $f(x)=0$ has (i) both roots less than 1 or (ii) both roots are non real.

Case (i): $x_0=\frac{(2-m)}{2}<1 \implies m>0$ and $f(1)>0 \implies m>0$

OR

Case (ii): $B^2\le 4AC \implies m^2+4m-12 <0 \implies (m+6)(m-2)<0 \implies -6\le m \le 2$

So the given function $g(x)=f(x)/(x-1)>0$ for $x>1$, if $m\ge -6$